# Move Rows using "contains" criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a Macro to move rows of information to new sheets based on certain criteria.

All of them work, the last one however needs to pull anything that "contains" text.

This is what I wrote, but it is not working.  Help?

Current code:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
i = 2
For Each r In Source.Range("E1:E3000")
    If r = "=*Wavelengths*" Then
        Source.rows(r.Row).Cut Target.rows(i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: `If r LIKE "*=Wavelengths*" Then` You need the **Like** operator for wildcard comparisons.

Comment: Also, double check that you really the `=` in `=Wavelenghts`. Could be accurate, but looks strange for text entry in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the instr function to return the position in which a string is within another. Check comments inside code to find behaviour explanations.

For further reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Try this code:

```
Sub MoveRowsIfContains()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Speed up things
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ' Beginning row 2 of target worksheet
    i = 2

    For Each r In Source.Range("E1:E3000")
        ' Check if string is in cell
        If InStr(1, r, "Wavelengths", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' --> The instr function. If you add the last parameter as "vbBinaryCompare" function is case sensitive, and "vbTextCompare" is case insensitive
            ' Copy the row to target
            Source.Rows(r.Row).EntireRow.Copy Target.Rows(i)
            ' Clean the source row (prevent cells from moving up)
            Source.Rows(r.Row).Clear
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r

    ' Back to screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This code should leave out examination of rows after each Cut. You may like to start the search from the bottom, meaning `Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)`. You would need to replace `For Each r` with a loop that counts rows instead.

Comment: @Variatus you're right. Thanks for the heads up. I provided alternative of copy/clear the original rows. May be useful for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook

        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Dim i As Long
        Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet

        Set Source = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng = Source.Range("E1:E3000")

        i = 2

        For Each cell In rng

            If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Wavelengths") > 0 Then

                Source.Rows(cell.Row).Cut Target.Rows(i)
                i = i + 1

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

**Note:**

If you want to delete the empty row after cut - paste you should loop the rows from bottom to the top using:

```
For i=Lastrow to ... step -1
Next i
```